# Multiple canonical definitions error when using GraphQL-Mesh

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation, graphql-mesh

I am trying to set up graphql-mesh federation with existing set of services that currently use schema stitching. Schemas were updated and federation was enabled in the services, and it seems to work with apollo-federation, but not with Mesh. When trying to run `mesh build`, I'm getting the error `Multiple canonical definitions`. I understand the idea behind the error, but the types don't conflict (the field sets don't intersect) and apollo-federation is able to build the supergraph schema correctly. Is there any way to get Mesh federation to work without having to extract a canonical type and import it somehow in each service (quite a bit of overhead)?

Example type definitions:
in schema1.graphql:

```
# Federation directives, etc above...

type MyType @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  field1: Boolean
}
```

in schema2.graphql:

```
# Federation directives, etc above...

type MyType @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  field2: Float
}
```

If I set up `.meshrc.yaml` like so:

```
sources:
  - name: service1
    handler:
      graphql:
        endpoint: http://example.com/test
        source: ./schemas/example/schema1.graphql
  - name: service2
    handler:
      graphql:
        endpoint: http://example.com/test2
        source: ./schemas/example/schema2.graphql
```

If I run, `mesh build` with this setup, I'm getting `Mesh Error: Multiple canonical definitions for "MyType"`. If I set up an equivalent `rover.yaml` for apollo-federation with the same graphql files, rover is able to successfully build a supergraph schema. Is there a way to make mesh-federation to work without having to extract canonical definition into some kind of a shared entity?

Comment: @James no :( Had to use rover instead